# Solving indexed ODE in Mathematica

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic

I would like to solve an ODE with indexed variables symbolically. Is there a way to do that?
$$\frac{dp_{\beta\alpha}}{dt}=m\left(p_{1\alpha}p_{\beta2}+p_{2\alpha}p_{\beta1}\right)$$
m is called mass and is constant. t is time.

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a direct way, by you can generate the list of equations programmatically, e.g., with

```
Flatten@Table[
  p[β, α]'[t] == m (p[1, α][t] p[β, 2][t] + p[2, α][t] p[β, 1][t]),
  {α, 1, 2}, {β, 1, 2}
  ]
```

Afterwards, you can apply `DSolve` or `NDSolve` to solve them (
suitable initial conditions provided).